# Silverlight datagrid group header customization

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a data grid, grouped based on employee name. I am able to group and able to show the group information properly. I would like to know, is it possible to add a check box along with employee name in the group row? I want to customize the group header to row.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using third party control Component one to achive what is required here easily. If any one is interested, please have a look at the following link
http://csharprambling.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/creating-treeview-using-grid-in-silverlight-component-one-cell-factory-iii/